# devtools::check fails with cpp_object_initializer

Tags: r

I run `devtools::test` and it works:

```
$ RScript -e "devtools::test()"
...
OK:       24
```

But `devtools::check` fails at a test:

```
$ RScript -e "devtools::check()"
...
> test_check("package")
Error in cpp_object_initializer(.self, .refClassDef, ...) : 
  could not find function "cpp_object_initializer"
Stan model 'bayes_logit' does not contain samples.
── 1. Error: Mixture of Dirichlet Processes stick-breaking works and returns (@t
'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
1: mdp_logit_mvn_stickbreaking(n_samp = n_samp, mix_mean = NULL, mix_cov = NULL, posterior_sample = stan_sample, 
       prior_sample_size = 1, dataset = german, tol = 1e-08) at testthat/test_stick_breaking.R:35
2: MASS::mvrnorm(n = n_samp, mu = mix_mean, Sigma = mix_cov)
3: eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
4: unname(as.matrix(x))
5: as.matrix(x)
6: as.matrix.default(x)
7: array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x), NULL) else NULL)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the difference between loading and attaching. I took the solution from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/176).

Add this in `NAMESPACE` to tell R where to find `cpp_object_initialiser`:

```
Depends:
    Rcpp
```

This works, but it gives you a note. To avoid the note, add an Roxygen export around the function that uses the Rstan call:

```
#' @importFrom Rcpp cpp_object_initializer
function_name <- function(...) {...}
```